# ajax ест контент

Tags: javascript, ajax

Делает это при его установке через метод `.html`:

```
function loadBans(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<%= WebConstants.servletPrefix + WebConstants.adminToolsMenuURL + "/" + WebConstants.adminToolsMenuUsersBanURL + "/" + WebConstants.getUsersBanURL%>", 
        data: {login: $('#login').val()},
        success: 
            function(data) { // can contain errors instead of user bans
                $('#bansContainer').html(data);
                prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", data);
            }
        })
}
```

Вывод(вывел [так](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591559/how-to-copy-text-of-alert-box)):

```
<form action = "/MVC/adminToolsMenu/usersBanManagement/changeUserBanState" id="changeBanStateForm0" method = "post">
    От: <input type="date" name="fromDate" value="2020-06-07" readonly/>
    До: <input type="date" name="toDate" value="2020-06-08" readonly/>
    <input type="submit" form="changeBanStateForm0" 
        value=

        "Сделать активным" name="doActive" readonly/> 

        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1"/>
</form>

<form action = "/MVC/adminToolsMenu/usersBanManagement/changeUserBanState" id="changeBanStateForm1" method = "post">
    От: <input type="date" name="fromDate" value="2020-06-07" readonly/>
    До: <input type="date" name="toDate" value="2020-06-08" readonly/>
    <input type="submit" form="changeBanStateForm1" 
        value=

        "Сделать неактивным" name="doUnactive" readonly/> 

        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="2"/>
</form>

<form action = "/MVC/adminToolsMenu/usersBanManagement/changeUserBanState" id="changeBanStateForm2" method = "post">
    От: <input type="date" name="fromDate" value="2020-06-07" readonly/>
    До: <input type="date" name="toDate" value="2020-06-10" readonly/>
    <input type="submit" form="changeBanStateForm2" 
        value=

        "Сделать неактивным" name="doUnactive" readonly/> 

        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="3"/>
</form>
```

Содержание `div-а` с `id` `bansContainer`(после исполнения. До был пустым):

```
<div id="bansContainer">







    От: <input type="date" name="fromDate" value="2020-06-07" readonly="">
    До: <input type="date" name="toDate" value="2020-06-08" readonly="">
    <input type="submit" form="changeBanStateForm0" value="Сделать активным" name="doActive" readonly=""> 

        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1">


<form action="/MVC/adminToolsMenu/usersBanManagement/changeUserBanState" id="changeBanStateForm1" method="post">
    От: <input type="date" name="fromDate" value="2020-06-07" readonly="">
    До: <input type="date" name="toDate" value="2020-06-08" readonly="">
    <input type="submit" form="changeBanStateForm1" value="Сделать неактивным" name="doUnactive" readonly=""> 

        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="2">
</form>

<form action="/MVC/adminToolsMenu/usersBanManagement/changeUserBanState" id="changeBanStateForm2" method="post">
    От: <input type="date" name="fromDate" value="2020-06-07" readonly="">
    До: <input type="date" name="toDate" value="2020-06-10" readonly="">
    <input type="submit" form="changeBanStateForm2" value="Сделать неактивным" name="doUnactive" readonly=""> 

        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="3">
</form>
</div>
```

Оно ест первый тег `form`. Почему ест? Как накормить ненасытный `ajax`?

Comment: что значит _Оно их ест._?

Comment: @Grundy Оно ест первый тег `form`. Ест - то есть принимает одно, а возвращает другое, уже без некоторых частей. Действительно, забыл уточнить, что ест то

Comment: а тут не "ест": https://jsfiddle.net/vo0wn19d/

Comment: @Grundy даже не знаю, что сказать

Comment: Очевидно, что либо тебе приходит что-то другое. либо ты проверяешь не тот код. В любом из этих случаев можно только гадать, что происходит, так как кроме тебя нет доступа к настоящей ошибке. Попробуй сделать пример, который бы воспроизводил бы твою ошибку, на том же jsfiddle

Comment: @Grundy Это единственный код на `js` на странице. Проверил несколько раз - выводит ровно то, что я вставил(кроме множества переносов спереди - я сейчас даже с ними проверил. То же самое). У меня такое ощущение, что оно просто пустыми строками заменило. `</form>` так точно.

Comment: без минимального воспроизводимого примера нельзя ничего сказать, но приведенный код работает нормально - ссылка это показывает. Значит проблема где-то еще

Comment: Поработал с кодом. Проблема исчезла. Причин не знаю, но, узнав, - отпишусь